# Collect RangeInclusive<T> into Vec<T>

Tags: rust

I think I may just be stupid but I can't figure this out.

I have a function that takes a generic integer type `T`, I create a range using that type `T` and would like to collect that range into a `Vec<T>`. The issue is that I get the following error `method cannot be called on` RangeInclusive `due to unsatisfied trait bounds`. It continues that the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `T: Step`.

Step in either `std::iter::Step` or `core::iter::Step` are both listed as unstable.

I did some digging and it appears that the Step trait is not yet [stable](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/implement-trait-step-in-1-76-0/108204/9). They also mention that the compiler error needs to be changed, but no info on how to actually do what I need to.

Some example Code:

```
use num_traits::int::PrimInt;

fn collect_range<T>(number: T) -> Vec<T> 
   where  T: PrimtInt + std::ops::Add<Output = T> + std::cmp::PartialOrd + Copy, {
    (T::zero()..=number).collect()  
}
```

Error shows up on the `collect()` in the last line.

My question, is this not possible, do I need to implement something else?

I suppose I can loop through the iterator myself to do it, but seems odd Collect does not work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I suppose I can loop through the iterator myself to do it

But you can't, for the same reason. The range doesn't implement `Iterator` unless `T: Step`.

Excuse the pun, but you can side-*step* this issue by simply requiring that `RangeInclusive<T>` must implement `Iterator`.  This also makes many of your bounds on `T` redundant.  Adding the `Iterator` bound and simplifying the existing bounds gives us this working example:

```
fn collect_range<T>(number: T) -> Vec<T>
where
    T: num_traits::Zero,
    std::ops::RangeInclusive<T>: Iterator<Item = T>,
{
    (T::zero()..=number).collect()
}
```

These bounds also more clearly express what's required for the function to work, so I would argue they aren't even a workaround -- rather, they are the correct bounds based on what the function does.

Comment: See I thought I was dumb. That makes sense now with the Iterator trait. I wasn't seeing the forest for the tree's and the compiler error didn't help things. You're also right that I can't loop through the range, but I can and did while I was waiting make the Vec directly using the range bounds.